# MySQL FOREIGN KEY error, ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, ddl

I have absolutely no clue why MySQL is having an issue with the second `CREATE TABLE` statement.

```
CREATE TABLE User(
    uid INTEGER, 
    url CHAR(100),
    firstname CHAR(40),
    lastname CHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY(uid)
);
```

The below is the one that causes problems:

```
CREATE TABLE Follows(
    uid INTEGER,
    url CHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(uid,url),
    FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES User(uid), ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(url) REFERENCES User(url), ON DELETE CASCADE
    );
```

Error I get is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(url) REFERENCES User(url), ON DELETE CASCADE)' at line 1

Comment: Remove the comma `,` before `ON DELETE`. That option is part of the preceding `FOREIGN KEY` constraint definition, and thus appears on the same line without a comma.  Generally, when MySQL points to the "right syntax to use near '", look to the character immediately before the single quote. That helps unless the message just ends there with the single quote, in which case the error occurred at the end of your statement.

Comment: @Kelbe: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-enforcing-foreign-keys.html

Comment: That is weird because I was following an example and it used FOREIGN  with a comma then ON DELETE. Looks like this: 
CREATE TABLE  
Dep_Policy (
pname  
CHAR(20)
,
   age  
INTEGER
,
   cost  
REAL
,
   ssn  
CHAR(11) NOT NULL
,
PRIMARY KEY  
(pname, ssn),
FOREIGN KEY  
(ssn) 
REFERENCES
 Employees,
ON DELETE CASCADE
)
http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~dbbook/openAccess/firstEdition/slides/pdfslides/mod5l1-2.pdf

Comment: @Kelbe I see. That slide has faulty syntax, I'm sorry to say.  The proper syntax is [outlined here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: I tried this and still get error: CREATE TABLE Follows(uid INTEGER, url CHAR(100), PRIMARY KEY(uid,url), FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES User(uid)ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(url) REFERENCES User(url) ON DELETE CASCADE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

First the `on delete cascade` is part of the foreign key definition, so the comma (`,`) before it should be removed.

Second, the second foreign key references `url`, which is not a unique key, and therefore is not allowed. So either remove this constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE Follows (
    uid INTEGER,  
    url CHAR(100),  
    PRIMARY KEY(uid,url),  
    FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES User(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Or define another unique key on `url`:

```
CREATE TABLE User(
    uid INTEGER, 
    url CHAR(100),
    firstname CHAR(40),
    lastname CHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY(uid),
    UNIQUE (url)
);


CREATE TABLE Follows (
    uid INTEGER,  
    url CHAR(100),  
    PRIMARY KEY(uid,url),  
    FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES User(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(url) REFERENCES User(url) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I would have been stuck for days if it weren't for you.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove after REFERENCES User(uid) and REFERENCES User(url) this ","

Comment: I tried that and it gave the same error. This is what I tried: CREATE TABLE Follows(uid INTEGER, url CHAR(100), PRIMARY KEY(uid,url), FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES User(uid)ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(url) REFERENCES User(url) ON DELETE CASCADE);

Answer (score 0):

you have to put a gap after User(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE, also you should write in to the end of the query like this: engine='innodb';

i mean between the last ) and ;