# FOREIGN KEY ON UPDATE CASCADE, Syntax error: Encountered "CASCADE"

Tags: java, jdbc, foreign-keys, derby, cascade

I have made a Users and Items table successfully using JDBC in NetBeans but executing the next two CREATE commands is giving errors.

**[Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState 42X01] Syntax error: Encountered "CASCADE" at line 10, column 19.**

The same error for the ***Orders*** and ***Cart*** table.

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
    FName VARCHAR(60),
    LName VARCHAR(60),
    Email VARCHAR(60),
    UName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PWord VARCHAR(60),
    PRIMARY KEY(UName)
);

CREATE TABLE Items(
    INumber INT NOT NULL,
    IName VARCHAR(80),
    IPrice FLOAT,
    QtyAvailable INT CHECK(QtyAvailable>=0),
    IDescription VARCHAR(200),
    PRIMARY KEY(INumber)
);

CREATE TABLE Cart(
    CartID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ItemNumber INT NOT NULL,
    Qty INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(CartID),
    constraint userIDFK
        FOREIGN KEY (Username) REFERENCES Users(UName)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT itemIDFK
        FOREIGN KEY (ItemNumber) REFERENCES Items(INumber)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Orders(
    ONumber INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ODate VARCHAR(20),
    OUName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    OItemNumber INT NOT NULL,
    Qty INT,
    UnitPrice FLOAT,
    OComplete VARCHAR(3),
    CardName VARCHAR(20),
    CardNumer DOUBLE,
    CSV INT,
    ExpDate VARCHAR(11),
    Email VARCHAR(60),
    PRIMARY KEY(ONumber),
    constraint ouserIDFK
        FOREIGN KEY (OUName) REFERENCES Users(UName)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT oitemIDFK
        FOREIGN KEY (OItemNumber) REFERENCES Items(INumber)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I had looked for a solution and I had found this a bit relateable can someone please help me out with the code.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30697331/6766368

Comment: which database is running in the background? Hmm... it is just a hunch, but try leaving out the ```constraint xyz``` lines. A table definition should be valid without giving the contraint a name and you do not need the ```CONSTRAINT``` keyword normally. But again, this is just a hunch.

Comment: Yeah, I tried removing the constraint line as well and it did not work anyway. I am using JDBC on NetBeans and trying to implement it with Servlet.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid code for MySQL - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2hyLqSvruDU4RpSmmqCD1m/0 - The issue must be with one of the used tools.

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: Can you also share the JDBC code you're running?

Comment: The problem was indeed with the tools that I was using it seems that derby doesn't support ON DELETE and UPDATE CASCADE.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-735

It is supported by MySQL but not derby.

Comment: If you were using Derby, then why did you tag MySQL?!

Comment: I am sorry I am a newbie to this. I figured out later that it wasn't a problem of MySql. Anyway, I have edited it. Peace.